# What does this statement (and another) mean in discrete math? Let $P:\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}\to\{T,F\}$, where $P(x,y)$ denotes "$x+y=5$"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What do these statements mean in discrete mathematics?

**Example 1:** Let $P:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \{T,F\}$, where $P(x,y)$ denotes "$x+y=5$".

**Example 2:** Let $B=\{T,F\}$. Let $P(p,q,r,\ldots )$ be a proposition. Then, $$P:=(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r:B\times B\times B\to B$$

Comment: What notation, exactly, are you confused about? There are at least 10 different symbols and notions here. The source of these examples likely has their definitions or a glossary of symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Example 1: is a very abstract and rather obscure but necessary way to say:

"$x + y =5$ is either true or false"

"Let $P...:$" means let $P$ be a way of writing a statement.

"Let $P:\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z \to...."$  means let $P$ be a way of writing a statement about two integers.  That is to say the *input* of $P$ will be $(x,y)$ a pair of integers.  So $P(x,y)$ will be a statement about $x$ and $y$.

"Let $P:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \{T,F\}$ means the *output* of the statement will be either TRUE or FALSE.  So given $x$ and $y$ the the statement $P(x,y)$ will either... be TRUE or FALSE.

So sayings $P(x,y)$ means "$x + y = 5$"  Means that we will evaluate any $P(x,y)$ as "Does $x + y = 5$ and we will determine that either ... yes, $x + y = 5$ or ... no, $x + y$ *doesn't* $=5$>

For example $P(2,3) = T$ because $2+3 = 5$.  And $P(4,2) = F$ because $4 + 2 \ne 5$.

....

The idea is that we are trying to use the algebraic concept of *function* in a logical context.

In this case "{{A}}+{{B}} = 5" is a statement that takes to integers as input and outputs a single T/F value.  In terms of *functions* this means $P$ is a function that maps an ordered pair of integers to a single T/F.  So the *domain* of $P$ is $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ and the codomain of $P$ is $\{T,F\}$.

Example 2:

We have three statements $p, q,$ or $r$ and each of those are either $TRUE$ or $FALSE$  and we want to know if the statement $(p\to q)\to r$ is $TRUE$ or $FALSE$.

So $P$ is the the statement $(p\to q) \to r$.

The input of $P$ is $(p,q,r)$ (not $(p,q,r,....)$ by the way; you typed that wrong) which is an ordered triple of TRUE/FALSE values. And the output is a single output TRUE/FALSE value.

So $P$ is a *function*.  If $B$ is the set $\{T, F\}$ then the domain of $P$ is $B\times B\times B$.  That is the set of all possible triplets.  That is $B\times B\times B = \{(T,T,T), (T,T,F), (T,F,T), (T,F,F), (F,T,T), (F,T,F), (T,F,T),(F,F,F)\}$.  The codomain of $P$ is $B = \{T,f\}$.

And the function is defined as $P(p,q, r)$ as $(p\to q)\to r$.

For example $P("bats\ are\ birds", "pigs\ eat\ corn", "Dogs\ teach\ algebra") = P(F, T,F) = (F\to T) \to F = T \to F = F$.

If we wanted foralize:

$P$ is the function:

$(T,T,T) \mapsto T$

$(T,T,F) \mapsto F$

$(T,F,T) \mapsto T$

$(T,F,F) \mapsto T$

$(F,T,T) \mapsto T$

$(F,T,F) \mapsto F$

$(F,F,T) \mapsto T$

$(F,F,F)  \mapsto F$

[Math *does* get fairly abstract.  But it *always* makes sense.]

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1**: The set of ordered pairs of integers such that the sum of the first and the second is 5. P(x,y)=xPy which means P is a 2-place predicate defined as x+y=5.

**Example 2**: The second one is the Boolean definition of Predicate. It, in essence, says given a relationship P such that p implies q whole implies r will give you an ordered triple such that the whole will be an element B={T,F}. That is, the Predicate P will be either true or false given the values of (p,q,r…).

This is what I understood of it.